# How to route to another page from a page that is not the main application page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am developing a simple website on React. Routing from the main menu to a page works fine but routing from a page to another page doesn't.
I have a page called "Locations" that displays a list of locations. Each location contains a list to a detail page displaying the location's details. 
The problem is that the detail location page is not displayed as another page in its own right; instead it is displayed below the location list page.

I am new to React so the solution to my problem is likely to be quite simple and due to a misconception of routing on my part. However, i was unable to find a solution to the problem online.

The problem is in this line:

```
<td><Link to={`/locations/${l.id}`}>&nbsp;Topo&nbsp;</Link></td>
```

in the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getApiUrl } from "./Utils";

class LocationList extends Component
{
    state = { locations: null, urlApiRead: getApiUrl('location', "read") }

    getLocationsAsync = async () =>
    {
        let response = await fetch(this.state.urlApiRead);
        let data = await response.json();
        console.log("Getting locations data:", data);

        this.setState({ locations: data });

        return data;
    }

    render()
    {
        if (this.state.locations == null)
            this.getLocationsAsync();

        console.log("Rendering, this.state.locations:", this.state.locations);
        return (
            <div align="center">
                <h1>Locations</h1>
                {
                    this.state.locations
                        ?
                        (
                            <table className="grid">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colSpan="2">Location</th>
                                        <th>Website</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {this.state.locations.map(l =>
                                        <tr key={l.id}>
                                            <td>{l.name}</td>

                                            <td><Link to={`/locations/${l.id}`}>&nbsp;Topo&nbsp;</Link></td>
                                            <td><a href={`http://${l.websiteUrl}`}>{l.websiteUrl}</a></td>
                                        </tr>)}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        )
                        :
                        ('Loading... please wait')
                }
                <p><a href={this.state.urlApiRead}>API</a></p>
            </div >
        );
    }
}

export default LocationList;
```

I expect the resulting detail page to be displayed on its own, just like any other page. However, it appears within th elocation list page, below the list.

See

https://www.remranger.com/rc-escalada/

Then Locations, then click on one of the "Topo" links.

What am i doing wrong here?
Thanks for helping out,

Rem.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an object to `to` prop of the `Link`, you should pass a string.

```
<Link to=`/locations/${l.id}`>
```

When you want to have other properties, you should pass them as object, like:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/locations/${l.id}`,
    search: "?sort=location",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you Amir.
Unfortunately, after making your suggested change, the detail list still appears under the original list page rather than appearing as a page of its own.

Comment: no, you should not add all those properties, that was just an example to show when should you have an object for `to` just use the first snippet

Comment: well the fact that component appears beneath the other, is related to your design. I don't see the parent of `locationlist`  if you can make a sandbox. it would be easier to trace

Comment: However, if i replace "/locations/<id>" in the Link to= by another page (e.g. "/about") it does load this page as a new page. 
May the problem have to do wth the fact i am using another variant of the locations page (extended with an id) and should i rather give the location detail page another name?

Comment: I don't know, it depends what the path `/locations/:id`  is rendering. it is not clear in this code. first, check if the path is `exact`

Comment: That's it, using the 'exact' tag within the route definition solves the problem, see below. Thanks Amir, for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem can be fixed by using the "exact" tag on the generic location list page.

App.js

Before:

```
            <Route path="/locations" component={LocationList} />
            <Route path="/locations/:locationId" component={LocationDetail} />
```

After:

```
            <Route exact path="/locations" component={LocationList} />
            <Route path="/locations/:locationId" component={LocationDetail} />
```

This distinguishes the root page from the parametrized detail pages.

Probably a typical beginner's mistake.
Thanks for helping out!